# Download google drive file using python in a docker image

Tags: python, docker, drive

I have the access token and file id of the file I need to download. After authenticating the user in a react application and using File picker API, I got both of them.
I need to pass them a python file that can download the file but without user intervention(without user permission )

Any suggestion on how to do it?
I do not have a shareable link. I have the file id and the access token after authentication. I need to download it through another application written in python.
Answers on stack overflow to download drive file using python have to do authentication using OAuth first, but in my case, I need to download the file without authentication

Comment: I closed as a duplicate based on the information in the currently only answer, but you might want to try to [edit] to clarify that this is different somehow, and should be reopened as a distinct question. The Docker mention in the title seems spurious, and isn't reflected in the question itself, but might be something you could elaborate on if it creates new challenges which are not solved by the duplicate.